# Using Azure Mobile Services in a C++ app

Tags: c++, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I want to build a Windows 8.1 Store app using C++.  I want to be able to use Azure Mobile Services as a cloud backend for my app.  My app is going to be a pure native app and from a performance perspective it is not acceptable to use some client SDK library which has been implemented in a managed language.  How do I do this using C++ only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2013, it is now possible to use a pure C++ based Azure Mobile Client library in your C++ Windows Store app.  The following blog post contains more details about this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/05/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-from-c-windows-store-apps.aspx